# Why don't treadmills offer a manual setting of longer than 60 minutes?

Tags: running

I know I can set a treadmill at the quick start setting and just run. But, why can't I set a program or the manual setting (which calculates calories burned) to longer than 60 minutes?

Comment: Wouldn't this be treadmill-specific?..

Comment: This isn't a sports related question.

Comment: @Marcus I believe it would be. If I was asking about shoulder pads, that would be on topic. A treadmill is a piece of equipment highly related to the sport of running. However, I do agree with Dmitry that this question is too localized. It would only apply to specific brands of treadmills.

Comment: On all the treadmills you can't do a workout longer than 30 minutes. I don't think it's a brand related question.

Comment: @glowcoder you are right, I must have been in a bad mood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The treadmill has a max time limit. Usually it's 60 minutes.
Even if you hit quick start at 60 minutes it will stop the workout.
Read how to change that limit [here](http://www.runnersworld.com/community/forums/shoes-stuff/treadmills/there-way-adjust-menu-life-fitness-treadmill).